# TFS 2015 behind a proxy

Tags: iis, tfs, proxy, iis-8, tfs-2015

Machine on which my TFS 2015 is installed, in order to access the internet, needs to authenticate and go through a proxy server. Obviously there is no need for it to access web in any way. However, the News panel in the main page overview on my TFS portal, fetches the news from web. I can see in the event log the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 23.52.183.215:80
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.Controllers.ApiCommonController.GetNews(Int32 maxCount)
```

As you can see from the event GetNews method on the ApiCommonController is unable to fetch the data.

I was keen to set the proxy access for the user (my TFS service account) running the TFS app pool, and I tried to configure system.net/defaultProxy in the IIS configuration editor, but with no success.

Does anyone know how to make TFS get to web via a proxy server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way to make it work. In the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services there is a web.config file used by TFS Web Services.

You should edit it and add the following:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://swg.eu.myproxy.com:8080" bypassonlocal="True"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Setting this, made my news load correctly and no more errors in the log.

Hope it helps!

Mario

Answer (score 0):

After setting the proxy access for the user  and configure system.net/defaultProxy in the IIS configuration.

- Please restart VS and your machine. The changes may not work
  immediately.
- Temporary disable any firewall (especially Windows firewall) and
  antivirus you have running.
- Also please make sure you have check the `Bypass proxy server for
  local addresses` in the settings of proxy server.

[image]